# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 14-20: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I got this error while writing to a file like this:
    `f.write(str(data))`
and the problem was I was calling str on some data that contained Unicode characters and the default "ascii" encoder does not know how to encode them to bytes. This I understand.

Then I did `print unicode(data)[13:20]` to see the offending characters and I could not see anything. Is there a way to detect that ? Thanks.

Based on Steven Kryskala's suggestion I did `print repr(unicode(data))[13:21]` and got this:

```
u'\n<body s'
```

Whats bad about that ?

Comment: Could you show what you had in data[13:21]?

Comment: sorry for the wrong answer, I miss understood the question

Comment: Try using `print repr(data)[13:20]` to see the bytes.

Comment: @bigOTHER It appears on the screen as legit characters.

Comment: call encode() function

Comment: What is the original type and content of `data`?  You mention in a comment below that `data` is a non-string object.

Answer (score 0):

replace with this try this

```
    f.write(data.encode())
```

Comment: data is an object of a class. It does not have `encode()` function like strings.

Comment: what is the source of data?? you cannot write an object of a class directly you have to define some function to serealize it or use pickle etc could you edit your question and paste your code please?